# Securely Storing Sensitive Images on Server - PHP/Ubuntu

Tags: php, security, ubuntu

I'm working on a project where the user will need to upload very sensitive images (think licenses, social security, etc..). This application is web based (PHP) and is hosted on an Ubuntu server. I will also need to be able to view these only by authorized users at a later date.

How can this be done? Encrypt the raw image data? What type of encryption?

Comment: do you want make them secure against web visitors or against server admins or both groups?

Comment: to be frank if you have no idea how to do it, maybe you should not do it at all. you will be putting sensitive data of your users at risk. start with building some projects that don't involve such security concerns and learn from there

Comment: @venca - Both, the images will need to be treated as credit cards essentially. Can't view after uploaded (unless authorized user). Encrypted on disk, etc...

Comment: @MicJaw - Well, I have built many projects. But typically they only have passwords which is completely different being that they are one way hash and not images.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to store files outside the public folder and then do this to get the file

```
<?php
//verfit the user and permission here
if (!$verfiy) {
    die();
}
$file_name = "fullpath/".$_GET['file'];
//check if 
if (file_exists($file_name)) {
    flush();
    $check = true;
    $filename = $file_name . '.pdf'; //extension
    $mimetype = 'application/pdf';  //what type of file you are requesting
    $data = file_get_contents($file_name);  //get teh file
    $size = strlen($data);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $filename");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    header("Content-Type: $mimetype");
    echo $data;
    exit;
}
?>
```

From protecting against the server admin use this

```
$password = 'passwod';
$outfile = 'download.zip';    
$infile = 'pic1.jpg';    
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");   
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$outfile");    
@system("zip -P $password $outfile $infile");    
readfile($outfile);    
@unlink($outfile);
```

It will create the password protected zip file and to get actual file back use the password to dcrpyt and unzip the zip file for the user

Comment: that is partial solution. still are available for server admins